# Dynamically Using Sheetname in Sql-VBA

Tags: sql, excel, ms-access, vba

```
rs.Open "SELECT [Sheet1$].ID FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE [Sheet1$].ID IS NULL ", cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

Sheet1, i.e. the name of the sheet in my case is variable in my case and I want to repeat this query for 100 sheets, so how do I dynamically specify the name?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you cannot call an entire worksheet in an Excel SQL ADO query but must specify ranges: `SELECT [Sheet1$A1:D50].ID FROM [Sheet1$A1:D50] WHERE [Sheet1$A1:D50].ID IS NULL`

And yes, since this is a string statement you can concatenate VBA variables within it.

```
firstsheetname = "Sheet1"

strSQL = "SELECT [" & firstsheetname & "$].ID FROM [" _
           & firstsheetname & "$] WHERE [" & firstsheetname & "$].ID IS NULL

rs.Open strSQL, cn, adOpenKeyset, adLockReadOnly
```

Comment: FYI..$ works in my case and I don't need to use a range. Also I added modified the above code as "[" & firstsheetname & "$]" and it works perfectly.Thanks.